# Reading variables - from classes that are located in other folders in project

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

**Class2**:

```
namespace readingvaraibles.Folder1
{
    class Class2
    {
        public int variable_1 = 1;
        public int variable_2 = 2;


    }
}
```

**Class3** that has also nested **Class4**:

```
namespace readingvaraibles.Folder2
{
    class Class3
    {
        public int variable_3 = 3;
        public int variable_4 = 4;

        class Class4
        {
            public int variable_5 = 5;
            public int variable_6 = 6;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to have possibility to read the variables from Class2, Class3, Class4 in the following class ?

**Class1**

```
namespace readingvaraibles
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: or do you mean they are in different .cs files

Comment: I hope these names are not your real names

Comment: The classes are in the same solution (project) but Class2 is in Folder1, and Class3 + Class4 in Folder2

Comment: I just want to read values of variable_1...6 in Class1

Answer (score 0):

```
      namespace readingvaraibles
     {
         public class Class1
        {
           public Class2 Class2 {get;set}
           public Class3 Class3 {get;set;
        }
     }

     var class1 = new Class1();
     var class2 = new class1.Class2();
     var variable1 = class2.variable_1;
     var variable2 = class2.variable_2;

     var class3 = new class1.Class3();
     var variable3 = class3.variable3;
```

etc...